# Alternative to QButtonGroup that allows no selection?

Tags: qt, radio-button

I'm writing a `qt`-based c++ application.  I have a number of buttons that I want to be mutually exclusive - only one can be toggled at a time.  I generally use a [QButtonGroup](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html) for this - it provides a nice logical way to manage sets of buttons.  When one gets pressed, the previously-pressed one gets unpressed, which is exactly the behavior I want.

This time, however, I'd like to allow for the group to be entirely unchecked. Unfortunately this seems to be disallowed by `QButtonGroup`:

> exclusive : bool
>
> This property holds whether the button group is exclusive.
>
> If this property is true then only one button in the group can be
>   checked at any given time. The user can click on any button to check
>   it, and that button will replace the existing one as the checked
>   button in the group.
>
> In an exclusive group, **the user cannot uncheck the currently checked
>   button by clicking on it;** instead, another button in the group must be
>   clicked to set the new checked button for that group.

There are a number of ways to work around this, of course.  I'm wondering if there's a pre-made alternative to `QButtonGroup` that allows this behavior, so that 1) I'm not reinventing the wheel and 2) I can stay within idiomatic `qt` to make project management easier in the future.

Any suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK nope. Especially in this case, Code required to get your functionality is very minimal. Just turn off the exclusive property off the button group when you want them all deselected in an event filter/mouse press event and sender object is same as current pressed button. Else turn on exclusive property if not on already.

Comment: Three years later, but I noticed today that when using autoexclusive instead of a QButtonGroup and Qt 4.8.6 I'm able to deselect the selected radio button. Not sure whether this is a bug or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to publish here one possible solution to the problem, as I just solved it in my case. Just beware that the following code is valid for Qt3. It may as well work for Qt4 and Qt5, because it doesn't use a lot of stuff.

So, I assume that I have a widget CustomWidget somewhere that contains buttons (of type CustomButton) and that one and only one button can be switched on. If one clicks another button in the widget, then the currently switched on button is switched off and the newly clicked button is switched on.

The CustomButtons contained in the CustomWidget are all contained in a QButtonGroup in the following way:

```
QButtonGroup* m_ButtonGroup = new QButtonGroup(this);
m_ButtonGroup->hide();
m_ButtonGroup->insert(Btn1);
m_ButtonGroup->insert(Btn2);
m_ButtonGroup->insert(Btn3);
m_ButtonGroup->setExclusive(true);
```

Here, Btn1, Btn2, and Btn3 are of type CustomButton

```
class CustomButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    CustomButton (QWidget* apo_parent = 0, const char* as_name = 0);
    virtual ~CustomButton ();

  protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* a_Event);
};
```

The method you want to implement specially is mousePressEvent. If its body is implemented in the following way:

```
void CustomButton ::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* a_Event)
{
  if(group() && isToggleButton())
  {
    CustomButton* selectedButton(dynamic_cast<CustomButton*>(group()->selected()));
    if(selectedButton)
    {
      if(selectedButton->name() == name())
      {
        group()->setExclusive(false);
        toggle();
        group()->setExclusive(true);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  QToolButton::mousePressEvent(a_Event);
}
```

then the widget behaves as you want.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt5, I use a similar solution as Laurent Michel's, but using the release event instead of the press event:

```
// Allow to uncheck button in exclusive group
void CustomButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* a_Event) {
    if(group()->checkedId()==group()->id(this)) {
        if(isDown()) group()->setExclusive(false);
    }
    QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent(a_Event);
    group()->setExclusive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another similar solution as the previous answers, but using `nextCheckState()` which appears to be the more natural extension point to me:

```
void MyButton::setSemiExclusive(bool value)
{
  mSemiExclusive = value;
}

void MyButton::nextCheckState()
{
  if (mSemiExclusive)
  {
    if (auto g = group())
    {
      auto old = g->exclusive();
      if (g->checkedButton() != this)
        g->setExclusive(true);

      QAbstractButton::nextCheckState();
      g->setExclusive(old);
      return;
    }
  }

  QAbstractButton::nextCheckState();
}
```

This depends on the associated `QButtonGroup` having set `exclusive` to false.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to extend the button class, you can also accomplish this by using signals (Qt5, Python):

```
from PySide import QtGui

class View(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        for button in buttons:
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(button)
            button.pressed.connect(buttonPressed)
            button.released.connect(buttonReleased)

    def buttonPressed(self):
        button = self.sender()
        checkedButton = self.buttonGroup.checkedButton()
        if checkedButton != None and checkedButton.objectName() == button.objectName():
            self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(False)

    def buttonReleased(self):
        button = self.sender()
        if self.buttonGroup.exclusive() == False:
            button.setChecked(False)
            self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(True)

    def manualDeselection:
        self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(False)
        self.buttonGroup.checkedButton().setChecked(False)
        self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to derive the QButtonGroup, set it to non exclusive internaly and manage the states by yourself

```
class myQButtonGroup : public QButtonGroup
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myQButtonGroup(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QButtonGroup(parent) {
        _bExclusive = true;
        QButtonGroup::setExclusive(false);
        connect(this, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)), SLOT(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)));
    }

    void setExclusive(bool bExclusive) { _bExclusive = bExclusive; }
    bool exclusive() const { return _bExclusive; }

protected slots:
    void buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *button) {
        if (_bExclusive) {
            // just uncheck all other buttons regardless of the state of the clicked button
            QList<QAbstractButton *> buttonlist = buttons();
            for (auto iBtn = buttonlist.begin(); iBtn != buttonlist.end(); ++iBtn) {
                QAbstractButton *pBtn = *iBtn;
                if (pBtn && pBtn != button && pBtn->isCheckable()) pBtn->setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }

protected:
    bool _bExclusive;
};
```